# Add elements of two array with each other

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have 2 Array of type Int like this

```
let arrayFirst = [1,2,7,9]
let arraySecond = [4,5,17,20]
```

I want to add the elements of each array, like arrayFirst[0] + arraySecond[0], arrayFirst[1] + arraySecond[1] an so on and assign it to another array, so the result of the array would be like

> [5, 7, 24, 29]

What would be the best practice to achieve this using `swift3`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add both the arrays like this

```
let arrayFirst = [1,2,7,9]
let arraySecond = [4,5,17,20]

let result = zip(arrayFirst, arraySecond).map(+)
print(result)
```

Comment: No need to use `flatMap`, the addition cannot yield `nil`. Just `map(+)`.

Comment: @NishchalAndroid The closure used for map has type `(Int, Int) -> Int`. The `+` operator is already a closure of type `(Int, Int) -> Int`. There's no need to wrap it like such. Just use `.map(+)`.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Yes there is no need for `map { $1 + $0 }` just use `.map(+)`, Thanks for correcting

Comment: There's nothing never stopping you from wrapping it more: `.map{ { { { $0 + $1 }($0, $1) }($0, $1) }($0, $1) }` :p

Comment: @Alexander, I didn't find the zip(_:_:)  method of the Objective-C version, what should I do?

Comment: `Objective-C version` of what?

Answer (score 9):

```
let arrayFirst = [1,2,7,9]
let arraySecond = [4,5,17,20]
```

First [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541125-zip) them, to produce a sequence that acts like array of pairs

```
let zipped = zip(arrayFirst, arraySecond)
// zipped acts like [(1, 4), (2, 5), (7, 17), (9, 20)]
```

Then [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688519-map) over the tuples, and apply the `+` operator:

```
let result = zipped.map(+)
// result is [5, 7, 24, 29]
```

All together:

```
let result = zip(arrayFirst, arraySecond).map(+)
```

Comment: It's likely because some might perceive my answer as being a ripoff of @Rajat 's answer and an attempt to steal rep. However, I added links to documentation, and improved the map call. I also up voted Rajat. Oh well.

Comment: Yes..It is as you said..I was following this question and since rajat made changes in his answer, you got one downvote..Quiet confusing how to deal with this.