# Add elements of two arrays in Swift without appending together

Tags: arrays, swift

Is there a neat way to add two arrays in Swift:

IE I would like

```
let arrayA: [Float] = [1,2,3,4]
let arrayB: [Float] = [10,20,30,40]

let arrayResult:[Float] = arrayA.map({($0) + ***stuck here***})
```

I would like the arrayResult to be [11,22,33,44] and not [1,2,3,4,10,20,30,40] that you would get should you were to do:

```
let arrayResult = arrayA + arrayB
```

I know it is possible with:

```
for i in arrayA{
  arrayResult[i] = arrayA[i] + arrayB[i]
}
```

But there must be a neater way than this using closures (that I can't fully grasp currently)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add elements of two array with each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542278/add-elements-of-two-array-with-each-other)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indeed there is an easier way. Zip then map.

```
let arrayA: [Float] = [1,2,3,4]
let arrayB: [Float] = [10,20,30,40]

let arrayResult:[Float] = zip(arrayA,arrayB).map() {$0 + $1}
```

edit: Even prettier from the comment below:

```
let arrayResult:[Float] = zip(arrayA,arrayB).map(+)
```

Comment: You can even shorten the `map` to `.map(+)`

Comment: @Hamish amazing! I didn't know map could take an operation like reduce can. Thanks!

Comment: @Hamish ..  and twiz_ you guys don't realise how happy that has made me- I was beginning to tear my hair out looking how to do this, thanks very much!

Comment: @twiz_ Yeah. `+` has type `(Int, Int) -> Int`, as does {$0 + $1}. You can just remove that unnecessary layer of wrapping

Comment: @twiz_ You could even take it to an extreme, and write: zip(arrayA,arrayB).map() {{{{{{$0 + $1}()} () }() }() }() }

Comment: @Alexander Well technically in this case `+` has the type `(Float, Float) -> Float` ;)

Comment: I don't know, I'm generally anti-bracket when I can be(). I wonder if this works for reduce with booleans? booleanArray.reduce(true, &&)?

Comment: @Hamish Oops, but yeah, same deal ;P